# What happens after level six of Midnight Magic?

Tags: atari-2600, midnight-magic

In the Atari 2600 game *Midnight Magic*, the board starts out as pink. if you hit all five of the colored bars at the top, the board changes to a navy blue (the color of the leftmost bar). If you then hit all of the colored bars, the board turns red (the color of the second bar), and so on.

I have always wondered what happens if you get to the point where the board is light blue (the color of the rightmost bar) and hit all of the bars. Unfortunately I have never been able to find out first-hand because the game gets harder with each level.

Does anyone know?

[image: Image of Midnight Magic]

Comment: While I can't answer your question directly, check out this high-score video on YouTube (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPzbYAUr2Ts; Part 2: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zThEnamG23A) where the player goes through several stages. The order of colors he gets seems to differ from what you describe, so it's hard to tell exactly, but it might appear as though you just get a new set of colors after you finish the current ones.

Comment: Thanks for the link. There's something wonky about the videos though. Throughout the entire first video, it remains at ball one even though it fell into the hole at least twice. I'll chalk that up to the "shoot again", but then the board suddenly reverts to pink for no apparent reason (and again in the second video). Plus the colored bars are different. I think it was played (with a possibly hacked version) in Stella. At least I saw what happens when you hit 1,000,000 points. `:-)`

Answer (score 4):

The screen goes black and you need to reset the console. I did this once as a kid and remember being very disappointed that there wasn't an ending to it.